# Noch oder erst am selben Tag?

Tags: adverb, phrase-request, time

ORF Online zitierte die spanischen Staatsbahnen RENFE in einem Bericht über das schwere Zugsunglück am 24. Juli 2013 bei Santiago de Compostela:

> Der Schnellzug sei noch am selben Tag einer technischen Inspektion unterzogen worden (…).

Das bedeutet, dass noch am selben Tag nach dem Unglück die Inspektion stattfand. Das war aber nicht gemeint, denn die Bahngesellschaft wollte darauf hinweisen, dass die Ursache kein technisches Gebrechen sein konnte, weil kurz davor eine Überprüfung stattfand. Am besten hätte man das mit einer kleinen Zusatzinformation so ausgedrückt:

> Der Schnellzug sei zuletzt ... Stunden vor dem Unglück einer technischen Inspektion unterzogen worden.

Wie aber drückt man die korrekte zeitliche Relation ohne diese Zusatzinformation am besten aus? *Erst am selben Tag kurz vor dem Unglück«* wäre eine Möglichkeit, klingt aber sperrig.

Offenbar gibt es keine kurze *und* prägnante Lösung dafür. Zu *am selben Tag,* egal ob mit *noch, erst* etc., schwingt für mich immer die Vorstellung von einem Zeitpunkt nach dem Unglück mit. Vielleicht geht es so:

> Der Schnellzug sei am Unglückstag noch kurz vor Abfahrt des Zuges einer Inspektion unterzogen worden.

wobei das *kurz vor* nicht durch die ursprüngliche Nachricht gedeckt ist, oder:

> Der Schnellzug sei erst am Unglückstag vor Abfahrt des Zuges einer Inspektion unterzogen worden.

Hier schwingt trotzdem noch eine unmittelbare Abfolge mit, die so nicht in der ursprünglichen Aussage enthalten ist.

> Der Schnellzug sei erst am Unglückstag vor der Inbetriebnahme einer Inspektion unterzogen worden.

Leider ist auch das problematisch, denn natürlich werden Züge inspiziert, bevor sie losfahren, wann denn sonst? Ist also genauso wenig eine sinnvolle Option wie *am Unglückstag vor Abfahrt des Zuges.*

Comment: Warum nicht _der Schnellzug sei erst am selben Tag einer technischen Inspektion unterzogen worden_?

Comment: Im Kontext finde ich "erst" übrigens in jedem Fall die schlechteste Alternative, da für mich hier immer die Bedeutung von "es wurde zu spät gemacht" mitschwingt.

Comment: @ Ansgar Esztermann — Weil "erst" entweder einen konkreten Zeitpunkt vor dem Unglück verlangt ("erst am Dienstag vor dem Unglück") oder einen expliziten Hinweis auf einen solchen Zeitpunkt ("erst kurz vorher"), sonst weist "erst" darauf hin, dass etwas zu spät passiert ist. "Am selben Tag" konnotiert aber eher einen Zeitpunkt nach dem Unglück. Ich finde, am ehesten ginge noch "am selben Tag erst kurz vorher".

Answer (score 2):

> Das bedeutet, dass noch am selben Tag nach dem Unglück die Inspektion stattfand.

Nicht unbedingt. Der Duden führt eine ganze Reihe von Bedeutungen des Adverbs "noch" auf, unter anderem auch

> (in Verbindung mit einer Zeitangabe oder einer Ortsangabe, die eine Zeitangabe ersetzt) drückt aus, dass der genannte Zeitpunkt **relativ kurz vor** einem bestimmten anderen [an dem die jeweilige Situation entscheidend verändert ist] liegt <sup>[Quelle](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/noch_nun_bis_jetzt_viel#Bedeutung3a)</sup>

In diesem Sinne ist der Satz offenbar gemeint und drückt korrekt den tatsächlichen Ablauf aus. Das Problem kommt daher, dass es eben auch noch eine weitere Deutungsmöglichkeit gibt, nämlich

> (in Verbindung mit einer Zeitangabe oder einer Ortsangabe, die eine Zeitangabe ersetzt) räumt ein, dass es sich um einen den Umständen nach sehr frühen Zeitpunkt, sehr begrenzten Zeitraum handelt, und betont gleichzeitig die Zeit- bzw. Ortsangabe <sup>[Quelle](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/noch_nun_bis_jetzt_viel#Bedeutung3b)</sup>

In diesem Sinne verstehst offenbar Du den Satz.

Wie kann man nun die Doppeldeutigkeit ausräumen oder die Gefahr eines Missverständnisses wenigstens deutlich reduzieren?

Aus meiner Sicht die einfachste Möglichkeit ist es, statt "technische Inspektion" auf eindeutiges Vokabular zurückzugreifen:

> Der Schnellzug sei noch am selben Tag gewartet worden.

Während "technische Inspektion" auch eine Untersuchung des zerstörten Zuges bedeuten könnte, kommt das für eine Wartung nicht in Betracht – es kann also nur noch die erste Bedeutung gemeint sein.

Ein anderer Ansatz ist es, sich klarzumachen, dass die Doppeldeutigkeit auch durch die Form der indirekten Rede provoziert wird. In einer normalen Erzählung könnte man den Unterschied nämlich durch die Wahl der Zeitform verdeutlichen:

> Am 24. Juli 2013 verunglückte in Spanien ein Schnellzug. … Der Zug war noch am selben Tag einer technischen Inspektion unterzogen worden. [im Gegensatz zu: Der Zug wurde noch am selben Tag einer technischen Inspektion unterzogen / auf technische Mängel als Unglücksursache untersucht]

In der indirekten Rede verschwindet hingegen diese Unterscheidung von Präteritum und Plusquamperfekt. Man könnte dies verhindern, in dem man die Aussage in einer anderen Form wiedergibt:

> Einem Sprecher der RENFE zufolge war der Zug noch am selben Tag einer technischen Inspektion unterzogen worden.

oder

> "Der Zug war noch am selben Tag einer technischen Inspektion unterzogen worden", sagte ein Sprecher der RENFE.

Möchte man bei der ursprünglichen Konstruktion bleiben, so kommt für mich durchaus "erst" anstelle von "noch" in Betracht. Im Gegensatz zu Dir und @Em1 sehe ich hier nicht die Gefahr, dass es im Sinne von ["nicht eher, früher als"](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/erst_zuvor_anfangs#Bedeutung2a), also zu spät, verstanden wird, sondern eben klar als ["nicht länger zurückliegend als"](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/erst_zuvor_anfangs#Bedeutung2b). Ansonsten käme vielleicht auch noch "[zuletzt](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/zuletzt#Bedeutung3) noch" statt "noch" in Frage, um den Zeitpunkt vor dem Unglück zu unterstreichen, aber das empfinde ich schon als recht holprig.

Comment: Vielen Dank für den Hinweis "technisch gewartet". Auf "noch" sollte man m.E. trotzdem verzichten. Doch jetzt kann man schon anfangen, die Puzzleteilchen zusammenzusetzen. Wie wäre es mit "Der Zug sei am Unglückstag gerade erst technisch gewartet worden"? Das finde ich schon ziemlich gut.

Answer (score 1):

> Der Zug sei **zuvor**, noch am selben Tag, einer technischen Inspektion unterzogen worden.

Ich persönlich finde es dabei etwas schöner, "noch am selben Tag" als Einschub zu markieren. Möglich ist es aber auch ohne Kommas, da würde ich aber die Reihenfolge von *zuvor* und *noch* wahrscheinlich tauschen.

> Der Zug sei noch zuvor am selben Tag einer technischen Inspektion unterzogen worden.

Man kann aber auf *zuvor* gänzlichst verzichten. Der folgende Satz zeigt deutlich, dass die Inspektion zuvor und nicht im Nachhinein stattgefunden hat:

> [Es geschah ein Unglück.] **Dabei** sei der Zug noch am selben Tage einer technischen Inspektion unterzogen worden.

Durch die Einleitung mit *dabei* wird offensichtlich, dass die Inspektion nicht infolge des Unglücks durchgeführt wurde, sondern dass trotz der Inspektion das Unglück geschehen ist.
In dem Fall kann man nun auch problemlos zu *erst* greifen, da hier kein Missverständnis mehr vorliegen kann.

Answer (score 0):

Es scheint so, als wäre das sprachliche Geschick des Schreibenden etwas zu kurz gekommen. Der zitierte Satz wäre vollkommen in Ordnung, allerdings in einem anderen Kontext, z.B.

> Es gab Hinweise, dass der technische Zustand des Zuges unzulänglich sei; daraufhin wurde das Fahrzeug **noch** am selben Tag einer Inspektion unterzogen.

Im angegebenen Kontext wäre **erst**, oder mit einem Zusatzwort (**zuvor**), wie von @Em1 vorgeschlagen, definitiv besser gewesen.